# How do i make a python oneliner for the following code involving two loops

Tags: python, loops

Here i am attempting to store sum values of list in another list
How can the following code snippet be converted into a python single liner, for example

```
l1=[(x,y) for i in [1,2,3] for j in [4,5,6]]
```

Here is my code

```
super =[]      #Empty list super which will contain sum of each list
for i in sub:    #First loop
    sum=0

    for j in i:   #inner loop
        sum+=j

    super.append(sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the same as your code

```
sum_list = [sum(i) for i in sub]
```

You shouldn't use `super` as a name, it's a built-in function name.

Comment: That was greatly beneficial. Thanks